# Raspberry Pi OS: udev rule xset does not set keyboard repeat rate

Tags: linux, keyboard, raspberry-pi, raspbian, udev

I created a udev rule with corresponding shell script to set the keyboard repeat rate when my usb keyboard is connected to the Raspberry Pi.

The script contains this line

```
xset r rate 250 50
```

as well as some other lines which print debugging text to a file which I have used to make sure the script is run by udev. (In other words I have verified the script runs, but it does *not* set the keyboard repeat rate - as if the above quoted shell script line was not in the file.)

I don't understand why the `xset` line has no effect.

I observe some strange behaviour in the debugging output files. It seems that udev runs the script **twice** when the keyboard is connected.

Here is the contents of the udev rule file

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/00-keyboard.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="<whatever>", ATTRS{idProduct}=="<whatever>", RUN+="/home/pi/udev/script.sh"
```

My thoughts are perhaps that something else (some other script maybe?) is being run **after** the udev script is run, and that this un-does my `xset` command contained in my script.

What other scripts / config files might be loaded after plugging in a keyboard/mouse device?

Edit: Running the `xset` command from a terminal works as expected

Comment: Well, udev rule is pretty much a wrong approach to do it. As implied by the name, `xset` is an X11 program that works on/with an X server. Normally you put the command in .xinitrc (or some equivalent file you use a display manager instead of `startx`). I don't know if there's some alternate program that has no X dependency but achieve what you desire "generically" though.

Comment: It's  possible though, to "forcefully" run it regardless of whether an X server has been started (yet). But you'll have to hard-code the `DISPLAY` env var, which is kind of ugly. (Yet it might be the only way to deal with the problem in your other question. I can also think of having some sort of "daemon" script that starts with X and `trap` certain signal, which udev can notify with `pkill`...)

Comment: @TomYan Interesting comment. Why does plugging/unplugging the device cause a reset then? Perhaps somewhere the x system has a script it runs when usb keyboards are connected?

Comment: Nah, probably it work like xset -> x server -> sysfs / libinput / ... ? So while you need x server to use xset, it does NOT mean X server actually take care of / keep track of the "states" / settings (which are volatile like the case of most other devices). But these are just my guess / deduction.

Comment: @TomYan Any thoughts on what the solution might be?

Comment: Btw it's not exactly an atypical case in Linux. Some times some developers just bind things to X (for whatever good or irrational reasons) and provide no other interface to adjust those settings, even when technically they are not X-specific.

Comment: I've already written what possible ways I might consider to implement for dealing with the problem. Not exactly interested to attempt/test it myself until I have such need personally. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So finally after digging around the net for one year I got it working today.

Source: https://newbedev.com/udev-rule-to-auto-load-keyboard-layout-when-usb-keyboard-plugged-in

As @TomYan already mentioned `xset` is an X11 program. So you'll have to hardcode the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` env variables.

Basically the workaround is to run the script in background with a short delay. So udev can activate the keyboard before you xset the keyboard. In the solution mentioned above the udev calls a script which in turn calls a second script in the background which then calls `xset`. In fact this can be shortened to one script.

*/home/pi/udev/script.sh*

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

(
    sleep 1

    DISPLAY=":0.0"
    XAUTHORITY="/home/codekandis/.Xauthority"
    export DISPLAY XAUTHORITY

    xset r rate 250 50
) &
```